# What is the best and quickest way to save a large Class Array in existing project? Realm isn't working

Tags: arrays, swift, object, save, realm

First off, I'm a relative amateur with app design having taught myself high-level swift/xcode last year, so apologies for my code in advance!

I've developed a game which has an array of a 'Player' Class called playerList. I currently convert this playerList array to JSON via Encoder and then save to device...however as my array grows, this exercise is beginning to take a long time, so I'm looking for an alternative. I presume the best solution is to rewrite the app to use CoreDate, SQLite etc, but I'm looking for a quick solution for now.

I could have used userDefaults, however steered away from this as large array and am instead trying to fudge a solution using Realm.

I've attempted the below, but whenever I look at my playerList after loading it is empty. Am I missing something obvious here, or alternatively is there a much better approach than using Realm?

```
class PlayerArray: Object {
    var iden: Int = 0
    var allThePlayers: [Player] = playerList
}

func saveViaRealm() {
    
    // Get the default Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    // Define player list
    let realmPlayerList = PlayerArray()
    realmPlayerList.allThePlayers = playerList
    realmPlayerList.iden = 1
    
    // Write to realm
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(realmPlayerList)
    }
}

func loadViaRealm() {
    
    // Get the default Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    //Retrieve objects from realm
    let realmOutputPlayerList = realm.objects(PlayerArray.self)
    
    // Filter to iden required
    let realmFiltered = realmOutputPlayerList.filter{$0.iden == 1}[0]
    
    // Assign to playerList
    playerList = realmFiltered.allThePlayers

}
```

Comment: There's a number of issues. The data is not saving because Realm properties need to be either declared as `@objc dynamic var some_var` or define the entire class to be managed with `@objcMembers`. Secondly the class is not named well. The PlayerAryay is not an array, it's a single object that holds a list of players but that's also not how to define a list in Realm; do this `let playerList = List<PlayerClass>()`.

Comment: Oh - one other thing; this .filter{$0.iden == 1}[0] may cause trouble. Realm objects are live, lazily loaded and using a Swift filter breaks that link and also loads ALL of the data - overriding the advantages of being lazily loaded. Suppose there are a million objects in the player list. Using a Swift filter will load all million of them into memory. When they're lazily loaded, it doesn't have that affect. So -when working with Realm, filter with Realm (it also keeps that live link as mentioned above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a read through the Realm documentation once more around Lists and declaring variables. In your object class are you getting any errors? RealmSwift should be declared with @objc dynamic vars. Also, you shouldn't need but one let = realm. Here is the link to Realm.io [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).